# Confusing and unclear youtube iframe api docs for playerVars property

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

In the docs of the YT iframe API The *playerVars* property should be explained on the *Supported Parameters* paragraph.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters
[image]

Comment: True, at best will waste time and possibly cause headache.